# How to make two columns line up to top

Tags: css, multiple-columns

Not sure why this is happening but when I scale down my page my right column (the one in yellow) moves down. It looks fine when I'm full screen but not sure what to do to the CSS to make sure the column contents always line up to the top of the div container. Here's my css for that section

```
.wrapper-cols {
margin-top:0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;
max-width: 900px;
}

.contact-col1 {
margin-top:0px;
padding-right:5px;
background-color:blue;
 height: 200px;
}

.contact-col2 {
padding-left:5px;
background-color:yellow;
height: 200px;
}
```

here's the url:

[link](http://atelierisabey.com/aisandbox/contact2/)

Answer (score 0):

The styles that are causing this to happen don't have anything to do with the code you've shared with us. There's a combination of stylesheets affecting everything in your website:

- Wordpress includes it's own CSS.
- The Beaver Builder Wordpress Page Builder you used includes it's own CSS.
- The Wordpress themes you're using (Avada and Fusion) each include their own CSS.
- Bootstrap is also mixed in.

So you've got all of these CSS huge libraries combining themselves, and the HTML you're using clearly uses their classes. At this point, the only practical way to make the website look exactly how you want it to, is to write the HTML and CSS code by yourself (instead of using a generator).

The non-practical way? Spend a few hours resetting all of the styles of the HTML tags involved, overwriting them with **!important** to make them behave as default. Be warned that this involves using some advanced CSS concepts to go **against** the libraries you're including (probably easier to write the code from scratch).